# Undestanding conditional SQL join , please see explanation

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2005

I am very new to sql.The actual problem is much bigger.
I need information in the following case. Say I have two tables like

**MemberTable**

```
MonthID  | UserID  | TeamID
-----------------------------
  1      |  1       | 6
  1      |  2       | 6
  1      |  3       | 6
  1      |  4       | 6
```

AND

**ReportTable**

```
ID* |  MonthID  | UserID  | IsSend
-----------------------------------
 1  |    1      |    2     | False
 2  |    1      |    3     | True
```

I need total count of users not present in ReportTable and the users for whom the IsSendValue is False i.e. count = 3

Is it possible to do that in one query? Please give explanation if it is not possible and possible solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT UserID)
FROM MemberTable
WHERE UserID NOT IN (SELECT UserID FROM ReportTable)
OR UserID IN (SELECT UserID FROM ReportTable WHERE IsSend=FALSE)
```

should return users with `UserID` 1, 2 and 4. A more concise query to achieve the same result is:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT UserID)
FROM MemberTable
WHERE UserID NOT IN (SELECT UserID FROM ReportTable WHERE IsSend=TRUE)
```

Comment: Yes. Corrected accordingly. Cheers!

Comment: Thanks. Actually I don't need DISTINCT as I have to group them with some other column.

Comment: @Web-E Then you can simply `COUNT(*)` or count on your specific field that produces the correct aggregate in your case. Cheers.